# Substantifs en -tat et -ta : pourquoi les deux suffixes coexistent-ils?

Tags: étymologie, évolution, suffixes, substantivation

La majorité des substantifs français finissant par le son *[ta]* et formés à partir de verbes ou d'adjectifs, s'écrivent **-tat** : *attentat*, *apostat*, *éméritat*, *consultat*, *excrétat*, *exsudat*, *habitat*, *résultat*, …

Néanmoins, certains noms peu nombreux ont une graphie en **-ta** : *[éjecta](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9jecta)*, *[excreta](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/excreta)* (qui appartient donc aux deux catégories) sont les seuls exemples que j'ai trouvé.

Y a-t-il d'autres substantifs en **-ta** que je n'ai pas vu (et qui ne sont pas directement importés du latin, ce qui est différent) ? Pourquoi ces deux terminaisons coexistent-elles, et observe-t-on un mouvement de « normalisation » vers la terminaison en **-tat** ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C'est bien une différence étymologique, comme souvent lorsqu'il s'agit d'orthographe française.

Les noms en `-at` proviennent en général d'une finale latine `-atum`, la finale du supin des verbes latins du premier groupe. Ainsi *[attentat](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attentat)* de *attentare, -atum* (variante *attemptare* qu'on reconnaît en anglais dans un sens différent), *[habitat](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/habitat)* de *habitare* (via le nom *habitatus* en latin médiéval), *résultat* de *resultare*, etc.

La finale est suffisamment fréquente (et reconnaissable) pour que le [suffixe `-at`](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-at) soit productif de lui-même. Par exemple *consultat* semble avoir été formé sur *consulter* sans parenté directe avec le latin *consultatum* (qui se trouve exister), et on a sans parenté latine *califat*, *rectorat*, etc. C'est un suffixe de substantivation qui a un large éventail de sens. Il qualifie en général l'appartenance d'une personne à une catégorie telle qu'une profession, ou la catégorie en elle-même. Il y a un autre type de sens, plus rare, qui concerne le résultat d'une action (*crachat*, *assignat*, ...).

Les noms en `-a` sont ici des dérivations savantes d'un mot latin en `-a` (neutre pluriel). Par exemple, *[éjecta](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9jecta)* provient de *ejectus* (un adjectif, via son neutre pluriel). Et *[excreta](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/excreta)* vient de *excretus*, participe passé de *[excernere](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/excerno)*. Cette finale correspond exclusivement à des dérivations savantes (les dérivations populaires donnent une finale `-e`), rares en elle-même (peu de mots sont importés au pluriel), ce qui explique qu'elle ne soit pas productive.

Enfin il peut toujours y avoir des coïncidences, comme *[apostat](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apostat)* qui vient du grec *ἀποστάτης* (encore que je crois que la finale a un lien de parenté).

Comment: You think *-της* and *-tus* (II) are etymologically related, or did I misunderstand? I believe the *t*'s (adjectival morpheme) are related, and the *s*'s (nominative morpheme), but not the vowels (different theme vowels?).